# how to make the bot give different value in every command

Tags: python, discord

I was trying to make a discord bot
I set my command to **?p** which will spawn a monster and we have to catch it
But whenever I turn on my bot and do the ?p command it just spawns the same monster again and again and also it gives the same roll again and again. This is the code -

```
import discord
import random
from random import randint

Mons = ["Ekans", "Pidgey", "Pikachu", "Espeon"]
random_mons = random.choice(Mons)

pokemon_roll = randint(1, 100)
pb_roll = randint(20, 100)
gb_roll = randint(40, 100)
ub_roll = randint(60, 100)
mb_roll = 100

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.content.startswith('?p'):
    msg = f'A wild {random_mons} appeared!'.format(message)
    await message.channel.send (msg)
elif message.content.startswith('pb') and pokemon_roll>pb_roll:
    await message.channel.send (f'{random_mons} broke out of pb, {pb_roll}, {pokemon_roll}')
elif message.content.startswith('pb') and pokemon_roll<pb_roll:
    await message.channel.send (f'congrats, you caught {random_mons} with pb, {pb_roll}, 
   {pokemon_roll}')
```

I want to the monster to be caught on the basis if the pokemon_roll is lower than the pb_roll
but everytime the same roll and same monster spawns

Answer (score 0):

You should define `random_mons` inside `async def on_message(message)`. Also, I think your indentation is wrong. Correct approach would be:

```py
import discord
import random
from random import randint

Mons = ["Ekans", "Pidgey", "Pikachu", "Espeon"]
# defining anything here makes it a global variable to this file

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # also better if you declare Mons here
    random_mons = random.choice(Mons)

    pokemon_roll = randint(1, 100)
    pb_roll = randint(20, 100)
    gb_roll = randint(40, 100)
    ub_roll = randint(60, 100)
    mb_roll = 100

    if message.content.startswith('?p'):
        msg = f'A wild {random_mons} appeared!'.format(message)
        await message.channel.send (msg)
    elif message.content.startswith('pb') and pokemon_roll>pb_roll:
        await message.channel.send (f'{random_mons} broke out of pb, {pb_roll}, {pokemon_roll}')
    elif message.content.startswith('pb') and pokemon_roll<pb_roll:
        await message.channel.send (f'congrats, you caught {random_mons} with pb, {pb_roll}, 
       {pokemon_roll}')
```

**Edit** based on comment, you can do something like:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # also better if you declare Mons here
    random_mons = random.choice(Mons)

    pokemon_roll = randint(1, 100)
    pb_roll = randint(20, 100)
    gb_roll = randint(40, 100)
    ub_roll = randint(60, 100)
    mb_roll = 100

    if message.content.startswith('?p'):
        msg = f'A wild {random_mons} appeared!'.format(message)
        await message.channel.send (msg)
    
    if message.content.startswith('pb') and pokemon_roll>pb_roll:
        await message.channel.send (f'{random_mons} broke out of pb, {pb_roll}, {pokemon_roll}')
    elif message.content.startswith('pb') and pokemon_roll<pb_roll:
        await message.channel.send (f'congrats, you caught {random_mons} with pb, {pb_roll}, 
        {pokemon_roll}')
```

Or, you need to define two functions, that will control the pokemon choice and another function that will take care of capturing.

Also, you might have to define what happens when `pokemon_roll==pb_roll` as this is currently not captured.

Comment: thanks a lot now my pokemon_roll and pb_roll problem is solved but a new problem arised which is that when I do ?p command on discord it says a wild espeon appeared 
but when i do pb it says ekans broke out of pb this is because it is just randomising the mons again and again
do u know some solution for that?

Comment: Yes, right. You might want to define two separate functions to deal with it.